# dynamodb enhanced : how to query using SecondaryIndex in java(spring-boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I just started with spring-boot-dynamodb enhanced.
[aws-skd-java2](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/enhanced/dynamodb) has examples to query with partitionkey but I couldn't find examples to query with secondaryIndex. 
Please suggest how to query using secondaryIndex with dynamodb-enhanced client.

Answer (score 9):

Figured out the solution.

```
DynamoDbIndex<Entity_Class_Name> secIndex = enhancedClient.table(
    "table_name", 
    TableSchema.fromBean(Entity_Class_Name.class)
).index("secondary-index-name");

QueryConditional queryConditional = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(
    Key.builder()
       .partitionValue(:value_to_query)
       .build()
);

Iterable<Page<Entity_Class_Name>> results = (Iterable<Page<Entity_Class_Name>>) 
secIndex.query(
    QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
        .queryConditional(queryConditional)
        .build()
);
```