# Is it possible to query dynamoDb table using only secondary key (SK)?

Tags: java, dynamodb-enhanced-client

I've a table structure, something like this

```
aws dynamodb --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 create-table \
    --table-name localTable \
    --attribute-definitions \
        AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S \
        AttributeName=date,AttributeType=S \
    --key-schema \
        AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH \
        AttributeName=date,KeyType=RANGE \
--provisioned-throughput \
        ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=5
```

and some additional fields storing some json string,  time, process details etc.

I want to query this table based on date rather than id (programmatically), but want to query single row for debug purposes using id ( like correlation-id, traceId etc).
My Program will pull 1k records use the data to some processing, but I'm not able to come up with proper queryCondition as AWS sdk expects me to provide both PK, SK.

This is the code I played with, LMK if something I've doing it incorrectly.

I've index too, but not sure how to use it using enhanced sdk, didn't mention

```
// sdk imports
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.ReturnValue;

....
 
/**
     * Get Documents between start date and end date
     * @param primaryKey primary key
     * @param secondaryKey sort key
     * @return payload
     */
    @Override
    public Payload read(String primaryKey, String secondaryKey) {
        return productTable.getItem(Key.builder().partitionValue(primaryKey).sortValue(secondaryKey).build());
    }

    /**
     * Read Record based on trace id
     * @param sortKey primary identifier
     * @return payload
     */
    @Override
    public Collection<Payload> read(String sortKey) {
        // tried enhanced query, but it expects partition.
        QueryEnhancedRequest enhancedRequest = QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
                .queryConditional(QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(Key.builder().partitionValue(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).sortValue(sortKey).build()))
                .scanIndexForward(false)
                .consistentRead(false) // no need wait for updates
                .build();

        //Tried Expression
 
        List<Page<Payload>> items = productTable.query(enhancedRequest).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        //tried scan
        Map<String, AttributeValue> start = (Map<String, AttributeValue>) new HashMap<>().put("createdAt", AttributeValue.builder().s(sortKey).build());
        Iterator<Page<Payload>> a = productTable.scan(ScanEnhancedRequest.builder().exclusiveStartKey(start).build()).stream().iterator();
    }

    /**
     * add item to dynamo db table
     * @param payload input object
     */
    private void addItem(Payload payload) {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->productTable.putItemWithResponse(PutItemEnhancedRequest.builder(Payload.class).item(payload).returnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_OLD).build()))
                .exceptionally(ex -> {
                    log.error("Unable to save item", ex);
                    return null;
                });
     }
```

I want to query this table based on date rather than id (programmatically), but want to query single row for debug purposes using id ( like correlation-id, traceId etc).
My Program will pull 1k records use the data to some processing, but I'm not able to come up with proper queryCondition as AWS sdk expects me to provide both PK, SK.

This is the code I played with, LMK if something I've doing it incorrectly.

I've index too, but not sure how to use it using enhanced sdk, didn't mention

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63786440/dynamodb-enhanced-how-to-query-using-secondaryindex-in-javaspring-boot